# OWIN separate login from subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'm using OWIN for my second site and everything was fine locally but now I'm having trouble when a user signs in on my first site mysite.com and then goes to second.mysite.com and I get this: Error An error occurred while processing your request.  I'm guessing this is because my first site uses the same cookies names as the second.  Here is an example of my Startup.Auth look like:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/signin"),
            CookieDomain = ".mysite.org",
            CookieName = "second.mysite.org"
        });
    }
}
```

I tried adding the CookieName hoping it would help but I still get the same error.  To sum this up I don't want my second project to use the same login as the first.  There is another older subdomain that uses the same login as my first site and I don't want this for this new site.

**Update**:
I stopped getting these errors when I removed the antiforgerytoken.  Setting the domain and machine key in the web.config didn't solve the problem it created more problems for me.

Comment: I would always have a new project for each subdomain/domain

Comment: They are two separate projects.  The first one is another cloud service that has <httpCookies domain=".mysite.org"/> in the webconfig and the other uses owin

Comment: hi, any luck with this, was my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie name must be the same, however You must use the same machine key on the different servers otherwise the cookie is not able to be decrypted by the other machine:

```
<system.web>
  <machineKey decryptionKey="<some long key>" validationKey="<another long key>" />
</system.web>
```

more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
and setting it up:
http://www.alexboyang.com/2014/05/28/sso-for-asp-net-mvc4-and-mvc5-web-apps-shared-the-same-domain/